# How do I convert a text string of NULL to a number?

Tags: string, r, numeric

I have input data from SQL which has fields that are the string "NULL", such that

```
unique(file$x)
```

returns

```
Levels: 1 10 14 8 NULL
```

I would like any of the results that are "NULL" to become "0" and then to convert using as.numeric().

I have tried:

```
i <- 1
for(i <= nrow(file) {
    if(file$x[i] == "NULL") {
        file$x[i] <- 0
    }
i <- i + 1
}
```

However, I get the result now that the NULL has simply turned into  and I am still unable to convert it to the number 0.

Comment: How are you reading the data into R? That's the step where you should fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're reading this in with `read.csv`, set the option `na.strings='NULL'`. This will import `file$x` as `numeric`, instead of `factor`, with numeric `NA`s objects in place of the `NULL` strings. Then to replace `NA`s with `0`s:

```
file$x[is.na(file$x)] <- 0
```

Comment: Thanks! This addresses the problem (though I'm sure many of these other answers also work).

Comment: Seems like for me usually the file$x[is.na(file$x)[ <- 0 command almost always fixes the issue when importing from MYSQL. The other times tacking on na.strings='NULL' and then using that command helps.

Answer (score 2):

In your SQL Query add: `ISNULL(myNullableField, 0)`

This makes sure that - if your value is NULL - it is converted to 0

it is a select query I presume?

Comment: In that case I'd recommend doing it via SQL rather then in R.

Comment: Where does this line go if I am using counts? For example:   SELECT a.id, count(b.variable) from a, b where a.id = b.id;

Comment: It goes on whatever field might end up being `NULL`, so I presume it'd be around `b.variable` as `COUNT(ISNULL(b.variable, 0))`

Comment: I get an error saying: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: That"s odd, are your `()` correctly placed? `ISNULL` requires 2 parameters, the nullable field and a replacement for NULL. So my example would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

In R:

```
file$x[file$x=="NULL"] <- 0
```

Comment: @sebastion-c I get the Warning message: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, file$count_profile3 == "NULL", value = c(1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated

Comment: Try `file$x <- as.character(file$x)` and then run the line, although it would help if I had a better idea of what `file$x` looked like.

Answer (score 0):

Although you should fix this problem at source (i.e. SQL), here is one way to do it.

convert the factors to characters, then replace NA by 0

I am not sure if this is right way to do for very big data though.

```
> x <- as.factor(c('1', '10', '14', '8', 'NULL'))
> y <- as.numeric(as.character(x))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> y[is.na(y)] <- 0
> y
[1]  1 10 14  8  0
```